# How do i Downgrade my React 18 to React 17

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have downloaded react 18 , but i want react 17 to work with, i have tried reinstalling node.js, creating a new work space  but no use , i have tried installing react 17 hoping that it would downgrade, but no use of that either. here is my package.json and the errors i get when i change the dependencies and run npm install

[My dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75mX2.png)

*[Warnings and Error that i get when i change the dependencies and use npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEuIR.png)*

Comment: Explained how to downgrade react version 18 tp 17 here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292332/downgrade-react-v17-to-v18-created-using-npx/74022224#74022224

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just uninstall the react 18
and install the react 17

```
npm uninstall react
npm install react@17.0.0
```

Comment: what about react dom ?