# Downgrade React v17 to v18 created using npx

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

How can I downgrade project created with "npx create-react-app . --template typescript".
All posts I find online suggest manually changing dependencies then to run "npm install" but there's always some error when I do that. How can I modify dependencies to make it work with react v17 ?

here's my attempt to downgrade :

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
"@types/node": "^16.11.36",
"@types/react": "^17.0.2",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.4",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

}

and here is errors:

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: hard-keys-react17@0.1.0

npm WARN Found: react@18.1.0

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

npm WARN   3 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.2.0

npm WARN node_modules/@testing-library/react

npm WARN   @testing-library/react@"^13.2.0" from the root project

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: hard-keys-react17@0.1.0

npm WARN Found: react@18.1.0

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

npm WARN   3 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^18.1.0" from react-dom@18.1.0

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@testing-library/react)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: hard-keys-react17@0.1.0

npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.1.0

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@testing-library/react)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.2.0

npm WARN node_modules/@testing-library/react

npm WARN   @testing-library/react@"^13.2.0" from the root project

Answer (score 0):

You could always run

```
npm resolve dependencies
```

Manually downgrading might throw some warning tell you that there are newer version than the one you are using now but its still work all the same.

And you made a mistake in your package.json

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

Make it

```
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade react version 18 to 17 after you create a project,
you have to do

`npm install react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2`

and replace src/index.js to this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
, document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals();
```